# Characteristic Polynomial of $A$ and polynomials annihilating $A$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

If $A$ is a real $3 \times 3$ matrix which is not diagonal. $p$ is a polynomial of degree 3 with real coefficients which is annihilating $A$. I have proved that if $A$ has a complex root (with non zero imaginary part) then $p$ must be the characteristic polynomial of $A$ upto a real scalar multiple, by using the result that $A$ is diagonalizable over $\mathbb C$. Is this true even if $A$ is not diagonalizable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's not quite true that $p$ must be the characteristic polynomial of $A$: the square, cube, or any power of the characteristic polynomial will do the same.

Secondly: consider the matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}$. What is the lowest degree polynomial you can find that vanishes on $A$?

For further exploration of these sorts of concepts, try looking up the concept of a minimal polynomial for a linear transformation.

Comment: @K Reiser sorry. I forget to say p is a polynomial of degree 3.